# how to hide the grand total row in views using @formula or lotusscript

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus

I want to hide the grand total row in views using @formula or lotusscript.
How should I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no Formula or LotusScript for hiding the grand total in a view, but I found a work-around for the cases where the grand total does not make business sense at all and would only confuse the users.

Displaying the view as an embedded view in a form, using `Show single category` leaves out the grand total row. You may need to use this view only as embedded view and have otherwise useless fixed category for all documents (i.e. put `"1"` in the formula for the categorized column and use the same in `Show single category`). You'll also need the `SaveOptions` text field with default value `"0"` so the users don't get dialog asking whether they want to save the document (after all, for them this is a view) and the line `Continue = False` in the `QuerySave` event.

Then you need to find how to best integrate this with the other views - maybe use `Auto frame` in the form properties if your application uses framesets. The users may not be able to tell the difference.

Seems like a lot of work for removing one line from the view but I am not aware of another way to hide it and sometimes it's worth the added complexity.

Does that help?

Comment: You're welcome! If your [new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5400137/locate-forms-into-view-directory-folder-lotus-notes) is about how to integrate this form in the navigation for the views - I used outline with the entry pointing to the form using (if I remember correctly) `@SetTargetFrame` and `@Command([Compose])`.

Comment: @Hristo- Actually I want this form to be seen immediately when I click the Previous Notes, just like the behavior of the views. I don't want to show the form using action button. I don't know if this possible. Any tips please. thanks. You help me a lot when it comes to lutos notes. I am a newbie in using this technology that is why I post lot of questions or problems that I encountered in my ongoing project development.

Comment: When you say "when I click the Previous Notes" do you mean the "Go Back" toolbar button? And the Outline navigation option I refer to is not about an action button. Actually, Ken Pespisa's answer to [your question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5400137/locate-forms-into-view-directory-folder-lotus-notes) will get you started with outlines in Notes.

Comment: @Hristo- do you have a simple tutorials regarding this? I cannot found a good article about Outline Navigation.

Comment: I haven't read tutorials - I have relied on the Notes designer [help for outlines](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/domhelp/v8r0/topic/com.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc/H_ABOUT_THE_OUTLINE_FEATURE_2035_ABOUT.html) and examples of use of outlines. If you haven't used framesets you may need to refer to the [help on framesets](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/domhelp/v8r0/topic/com.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc/H_OVERVIEW_OF_FRAMESETS_OVER.html) too.

Answer (score 1):

You can also create a Filtered By Category view by using @SetViewInfo with first column with value "1" and filter by this values. All documents will be displayed only total sum will be hidden.