# locate forms into view directory folder lotus notes

Tags: lotus-notes

I created a form to display a specific report instead of a view. iwant the form to locate into the directory folder in which views located. for eg I have a view at 1. Reports\a. Quarterly Reports, I want the reports be to located at 1. Reports\b. No of Request per Country(this is the form). So that when I view the reports they are only in one location. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ken has good points about the design of the solution. If you need more direct assistance, then I can offer the following solution.

As you're now using a variety of design elements. You need to unify it using a frameset and an outline. Framesets in Notes are the generally the same as their web counterpart. The great thing with Notes is that you can easily add this to your current design.

I would recommend the following order of tasks.

1. Create the outline. Instructions [here](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/domhelp/v8r0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc/H_CREATING_AN_OUTLINE_STEPS.html)
2. Create the frameset and connect the outline to it. Instructions [here](http://www-12.lotus.com/ldd/doc/domino_notes/rnext/help6_designer.nsf/b3266a3c17f9bb7085256b870069c0a9/99f40f36ee5da09a85256c54004b71e0?OpenDocument).
3. Set the database launch properties so the frameset loads up when people open the database. Instructions [here](http://www-12.lotus.com/ldd/doc/domino_notes/rnext/help6_designer.nsf/f4b82fbb75e942a6852566ac0037f284/b701ed7936f8b76085256c54004b9676?OpenDocument).

Even though the links point to Lotus Notes version 6, the functionality is still applicable in version 7 and 8. The only other point I would make is that when you click on an outline element it needs to know where the target location to display the data. You define this on the frames in the framesets. Just look at the menu option "Frames" and select "Frame properties" or "Frameset properties" respectively.

Comment: @Giulio- I already solved this problem. Many thanks for  the references you've provided i appreciated it very much.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Notes Outline to manage this.  Set one up for your database, if you haven't already, and use it as your left-hand navigation in your frameset.  If you aren't sure what I'm talking about, try creating a new database based on the Document Library template and take a look at the design.  It'll have a frameset, and on the left frame it'll have a Notes Outline.

Once you have your database setup like that, you can control what the user sees in that outline by creating hierarchical outline entries.  You can link views, pages, and forms to your outline entries and that way you can have your 1. Reports\a. Quarterly Reports view showing next to your 1. Reports\b.No of Request Per Country form (report).

Even better, you can use different names.  Since an Outline manages its order, you don't need to name your entries 1., 2., etc to get them to show in a certain order.  You can name them whatever you like and rearrange them in the Outline design screen.

Comment: @ken- Sorry I am a newbie in lotus notes. I try to search on the web if there is a tutorials about this one. But I can't find a better articles on this. Will you be able to provide me a step by step on how to do this. I will appreciate all your help.Thank you.